# Como encriptar e decriptar dados a serem transmitidos via sockets?

Tags: socket, criptografia, cliente-servidor, lado-do-cliente, tcpclient

Tenho um programa que faz login com o meu server, no entanto a conexão está sem qualquer proteção. Procurei por alguns modos de proteger mas parece que alguns deles têm uma pass code, no client, mas eu preciso de fazer a conexão criptografada, e impedir que a pessoa que tem o client consiga perceber como interceptar a conexão de outros usuários, como e que eu devo resolver isto?

Comment: Qual a linguagem utilizada? Você está usando algum *webserver* como Apache, Tomcat, IIS, etc, ou seu servidor é um programa comum? Eu sugiro simplesmente usar SSL/TLS, mas para dar um exemplo eu precisaria da linguagem (praticamente todas elas possuem alguma biblioteca pronta para auxiliar com isso, o mais "chato" é configurar corretamente o certificado).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode encriptar os dados a serem enviados enviados e decriptar os dados a serem recebidos via sockets, com o algoritmo [AES](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43492/como-funciona-o-algoritmo-de-criptografia-aes?rq=1).

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES {

private byte[] chave;
private byte[] mensagem;

public AES(byte[] chave, byte[] mensagem) {
    this.chave = chave;
    this.mensagem = mensagem;
}

public AES() {
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    byte[] mensagem = "oi".getBytes();
    byte[] chave = "0123456789abcdef".getBytes();

    System.out.println("Tamanho da chave: " + chave.length);

    byte[] encriptado = Encripta(mensagem, chave);
    System.out.println("String encriptada: " + new String(encriptado));

    byte[] decriptado = Decripta(encriptado, chave);
    System.out.println("String decriptada: " + new String(decriptado));

}

public static byte[] Encripta(byte[] msg, byte[] chave) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(chave, "AES"));
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(msg);
    return encrypted;
}

public static byte[] Decripta(byte[] msg, byte[] chave) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(chave, "AES"));
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(msg);
    return decrypted;
}
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que uma forma de resolver o seu problema é o servidor solicitar um login e por uma medida de segurança, o cliente informa apenas o hash deste login ao servidor, e nunca em texto plano. Posteriormente o servidor utiliza uma chave associada aquele login (pode ser um pedaço do hash da senha daquele usuário, que já está salva no servidor) para encriptar os dados utilizando o AES. No cliente você repete o algoritmo, faz o hash da senha e o utiliza como chave do AES. Se a senha for igual ao do servidor, ambos utilizarão a mesma chave e a comunicação vai ocorrer de forma fluída e protegida.

Acho que é desnecessário você informar a senha ao servidor, uma vez que com uma decriptação correta dos dados já subentende-se que o cliente informou a senha correta. Mas caso isto seja necessário, recomendo que nunca envie a senha em texto plano. Envie o hash da senha e [certifique-se de que você está fazendo isto de forma segura.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)

**Editado**

Por sugestão do [mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/215/mgibsonbr) é interessante que você utilize algoritmos de hash mais demorados, como o PBKDF2, BCrypt ou scrypt. Acredito que se você utilizer o utilizar o SHA-3, mas com uma maior quantidade de iterações (1000x, por exemplo) também terá um efeito semelhante.

Comment: A ideia geral está ok, mas há alguns detalhes que tornam essa abordagem bastante insegura: 1) "este pode ser transmitido publicamente, sem proteção nenhuma" e se alguém interceptar esse login, ele vai descobrir a senha? O login precisa de proteção sim! 2) Use um modo de operação mais seguro, como o CBC ou CTR, nunca o ECB. [Onde está o pinguim?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) 3) Derivar uma chave a partir da senha está ok, mas use um hash lento como PBKDF2 ou BCrypt ou scrypt, ou ficará vulnerável a ataques de busca exaustiva.

Comment: @mgibsonbr por que o login não pode ser transmitido dessa forma se a senha estará protegida? Deve-se passar um hash no login também? 2) Corrigido 3) Corrigido. Obrigado pelas suas sugestões, fique a vontade para modificar e incrementar a minha resposta.

Comment: Quando o cliente enviar a senha pro servidor, se isso for feito em texto plano qualquer um pode interceptar essa senha, e ou executar um MitM ou posteriormente fazer login como aquele usuário. Aí, todo o resto vai por água abaixo. Uma opção seria usar um protocolo onde o cliente *não revela* a senha pro servidor, como o SRP, outra seria simplesmente usar SSL (estou tentando escrever uma resposta nesse sentido). P.S. Fui eu que negativei, porque o ponto 1 é o mais sério, e como sua resposta está *aceita* apesar desse problema, achei necessário sinalizar isso de forma clara. Corrija e eu retiro.

Comment: Acho que me expressei mal. A ideia que tive é de passar o hash na senha do usuário e utilizar uma parte deste hash como chave para o AES. Portanto, apenas o login seria informado em texto plano, o cliente informaria a senha para o servidor já com os dados encriptados (ou nem precisaria enviar a senha, já que a comunicação já seria encriptada e uma decriptação correta por parte do servidor já entende-se que o cliente informou a senha correta).

Comment: No servidor, o mesmo algoritmo seria executado, pois o hash da senha já estaria no banco de dados, bastando apenas utilizar uma parte dele como chave. Vou editar minha resposta novamente.

Comment: Ok, melhorou bastante, já retirei o voto negativo. Essa estratégia ainda não é totalmente segura (é vulnerável a ataques de replay, por exemplo, e usar uma parte do hash como chave anula o benefício de se usar um hash), mas os problemas são menores se feito dessa forma (sem o cliente enviar a senha pro servidor).

Comment: Um ataque de replay seria usar um sniffer de rede e repetir os dados encriptados? De que forma poderia melhorar essa técnica sem utilizar o hash como senha? Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em que utilizo algo parecido com o que fiz na minha resposta. Posso abusar do seu conhecimento e fazer uma pergunta? Este é um assunto que me interessa bastante. =P

Comment: Haha eu ia justamente sugerir isso! :) Se quiser fazer uma pergunta, vá em frente, mas se preferir pode também me chamar no chat e eu explico melhor o que quis dizer.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23628/discussion-between-avelino-and-mgibsonbr).