# Algoritimos de Hash e Criptografia

Tags: criptografia, hash

Estou fazendo um trabalho sobre a diferença entre Hash e Criptografia.

Para mim é mais fácil falar sobre Hash e citar exemplos já que eu costumo usar SHA1 e MD5, mas falar sobre criptografia é difícil já que não conheço nenhum algoritmo de criptografia.

Queria exemplos mais próximos do cotidiano do programador, mas sempre acabo encontrando só hashs e nenhum de criptografia de fato.

Alguém pode citar exemplos de algoritmos de criptografia?

Comment: Eu creio que a pergunta seja meio ampla para o formato do SOpt, mas de toda sorte, meus dois centavos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43492/64969

Comment: Quando preciso ver alguma coisa de segurança/criptografia, normalmente eu cavo as respostas do [mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/215/mgibsonbr) no assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A215+%5Bseguran%C3%A7a%5D

Comment: Alguma base matemática de um canal no YT que eu gosto muito: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12Q3Mrh03Gk ; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOs34_-eREk ;

Comment: Gente, vocês sabem se o Base64 é um algoritmo de criptografia?

Comment: Não, base64 é só um padrão de codificação. Se você assumir que base64 criptografa dados, então usar números romanos está criptografando decimais.

Comment: Entendi, obrigada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo as definições de dicionário, criptografia é *"um conjunto de princípios e técnicas empregadas para cifrar a escrita, torná-la ininteligível para os que não tenham acesso às convenções combinadas"*.

Ou seja, qualquer algorítimo que torne o conteúdo não legível ou interpretável podemos pensar, de uma maneira simples, como criptografia, ou mais simples ainda, qualquer algorítimo que "embaralhe" os dados.

Veja o exemplo abaixo, que peguei desse site: [http://www.henryalgus.com](http://www.henryalgus.com/creating-basic-javascript-encryption-between-frontend-and-backend/)

```js
var jsEncode = {
 encode: function (s, k) {
  var enc = "";
  var str = "";
  // make sure that input is string
  str = s.toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
   // create block
   var a = s.charCodeAt(i);
   // bitwise XOR (operação lógica que "mexe" nos bits, gerando o efeito de "embaralhar" o caractere)
   var b = a ^ k;
   enc = enc + String.fromCharCode(b);
  }
  return enc;
 }
};

var chave = "123";
var e = jsEncode.encode("Teste de criptografia",chave);
console.log("dados criptografados: " + e);
var d = jsEncode.encode(e,chave);
console.log("dados descriptografados: " + d);
```

É um simples exemplo que faz uma criptografia simples, um exemplo prático próximo do cotidiano de programação como você mencionou.

Hash já é um cálculo matemático, que gerar uma representação numérica de um dado. 
A principal característica do hash é que ele não é revertido, ou "descriptografado" por assim dizer, diferente do exemplo acima, ou de outros algorítimos mais usados, como esses:

- Criptografia com chave simétrica: é usada uma mesma chave para criptografar criptografar e descriptografar os dados.
  Entre os algoritimos que usam essa técnica estão DES (*Data Encryption Standard*), e RC (*Ron's Code* ou *Rivest Cipher*) (RC2, RC4, etc)
- Criptografia com chave assimétrica, ou chave pública.
  Trabalha com duas chaves: uma privada e outra pública. A chave pública é usada para criptografar, e ao enviar os dados para alguém (ou algum lugar), deve mandar separadamente a uma chave privada, para que os dados possam ser descriptografados.
  Alguns exemplos:
  RSA (*Rivest, Shamir and Adleman*) e ElGamal

Outros algorítimos conhecidos, principalmente em redes WiFi são WEB e WPA.

Referências: [http://pcworld.com.br/](http://pcworld.com.br/reportagens/2007/10/05/idgnoticia.2007-10-04.0383475254/)

Comment: Bem didática sua resposta. Só não dou como certa ainda pra movimentar os comentários. :)

Comment: Sim, quanto mais comentários e respostas melhor pra comunidade :)

Comment: Esse exemplo é de criptografia com chave simétrica, ne?

Comment: A definição do dicionário não é muito técnica. E seria melhor na sua colocar um E no lugar do OU, porque Base64 não é criptografia e muitos acham que é. Ele é interpretável, apesar de ilegível.

Comment: Eu até votei na resposta, mas não sou muito fã porque pede um exemplo sem critério algum, é um "posta qualquer coisa aí".

Comment: WEP e WPA, no caso?

Comment: *"A definição do dicionário não é muito técnica"* sim @Maniero, você tem razão, mas o intuito era exatamente esse nesse caso :)
Era pra dar uma base bem "simples" do que seria apenas "embaralhar" os dados, para o exemplo de código `javascript` que inclui